# How does enumerating powerline adapters work?

Tags: networking, powerline-networking

Some proprietary softwares (like router softwares, or proprietary desktop applications to manage powerline devices) offer a way to enumerate powerline adapters.

For example, on Netgear Genie, we have a nice map of powerline adapters:
[image]

How does it work in practice? Is it using a protocol like LLDP?
More precisely, considering the fact that this map is 100% generated from a desktop connected to the network (with no a-priori knowledge of the powerline devices), how does it enumerate these powerline devices?

Additionnaly, is there any way to get this mapping using free/open-source (and vendor-agnostic) softwares?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How does it work in practice? Is it using a protocol like LLDP?

Not sure about G.hn powerline devices, but the HomePlug AV powerline specification does have a "HomePlug Management Protocol" (see [chapter 11](https://docbox.etsi.org/Reference/homeplug_av21/homeplug_av21_specification_final_public.pdf#page=647)) which is accessible through the Ethernet side of those devices. You can query their status, reboot them, change the network keys, etc.

HomePlug Management Protocol is not IP-based; it uses its own Ethertype 0x88e1. Most commands can be broadcast, or sent to a special "Nearest HomePlug device" MAC (it's pretty unlikely that the same ethernet would be directly attached to two powerline bridges at once), or sent to a specific device's MAC address. It's completely unauthenticated, so anyone on the same VLAN can reconfigure all of your HomePlug adapters.

Enumeration is done by asking the nearest device for a list of network members – not by querying them individually.

The protocol also has a facility for relaying commands over powerline to HomePlug devices which are not currently participating in the network. (This is where you need the "device access keys" printed on each adapter.)

> Additionnaly, is there any way to get this mapping using free/open-source (and vendor-agnostic) softwares?

Most HomePlug AV software *is* vendor-agnostic to some extent. You can most likely use the same adapters with Netgear software, TP-Link software, and TrendNet software.

(Though, another thing about "vendor-agnostic" is that basically all vendors just use the same HomePlug AV chips made by Qualcomm. You're not actually talking to a Netgear device – you're talking to a QCA device in a Netgear-branded box. And I believe most of the HomePlug AV software actually do use QCA-specific commands, they just happen to be the same on all devices.)

Qualcomm actually publish an open-source set of command-line tools, [open-plc-utils](https://github.com/qca/open-plc-utils), which can give you most of the same features. You won't get a fancy map with that, but you don't really *need* one – an HPAV network is flat, with all devices directly talking to each other. (From what I know, HPAV does not have mesh/relay facilities like G.hn does.) Notice that the map in Genie is just a star with no complexity to it...

To ask the nearest HPAV adapter to give you a list of devices on the network (as well as their roles, speeds, and nearest Ethernet device), use `plcstat -m` or `plcstat -t` or `plctool -m`, all doing mostly the same thing:

```
$ plcstat -i wlan0 -m local
 NID 9A:09:7C:A3:D1:47:0E SNID 008
 STA TEI 002 MAC 34:E8:94:6C:E2:xx BDA 48:5D:60:xx:xx:xx
 CCO TEI 001 MAC 34:E8:94:6C:E6:xx BDA FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF TX 009 RX 009
```

To get the PHY error statistics, use `plcstat -s CSMA-ALL -d both`. To reboot a bridge that tends to get stuck, use `plctool -R`.

To get the *local* device's Parameter Information Block, use `plctool -I` – among other things, this will give you the PBKDF1  hash of the network's NMK, which can then be programmed into another device using `plctool -M` or `-J`.

Comment: Looks like my powerline adapter (PLP1000) is using a [broadcom chip](https://deviwiki.com/wiki/List_of_PowerLine_Devices) and open-plc-utils is [only supporting QCA chips](https://github.com/qca/open-plc-utils/issues/67), this would explain why `plcstat` doesn't return anything.
(BTW cannot restrain myself to thank you for this super clear answer!)

Comment: I see -- in that case, try _all_ of the plcstat or plctool options; I think some of them actually issue generic management commands, while others use QCA-specific ones. (For example, I _think_ this was the difference between `-m` vs `-t`.) You might also want to try the older `int6kstat` tool which is part of the same package (though that too is aimed at the Qualcomm-absorbed Atheros/Intellon INT6xxx, not Broadcom).

Comment: No luck to get an answer from the adapter using any combination of open-plc-utils commands.
However, this third-party implementation, [pla-util](https://github.com/serock/pla-util), worked to communicate with my PLP1000!

Comment: Thank you all! Spent waaaay too long trying to figure out why `plctool` was working in some cases but not others! It's a bit tricky to talk to these at all with VLANs set up (https://forum.openwrt.org/t/viewing-powerline-status-from-tp-link-wpa8630p-v2/97040/6) but I think my main problem in the end is trying to talk to a Broadcom-based (TL-PA7017) chipset with the Qualcomm-provided tools (which *did* work with e.g. TL-WPA8630 and what kept me futilely trying for so long…)!